# Understanding the use of classes when training a neural network with Pytorch

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I'm currently reading about using the cross-entropy loss to train a neural network in the [pytorch documentation](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html#define-a-loss-function-and-optimizer). The criterion that is to be used to calculate the loss is called as follows

```
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
```

According to the [`torch.nn` documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#crossentropyloss), `CrossEntropyLoss` is a class. From my understanding this would mean that `criterion` is an object of type `nn.CrossEntropyLoss`.

When training the neural network, `criterion` is used to calculate the loss in the following way

```
loss = criterion(input, target)
```

This is somewhat confusing to me. **If** `criterion` **is an object, then how can it be used as a function?** What I would expect is something like

```
loss = criterion.calculate_loss(input, target)
```

where `calculate_loss()` would be a method defined in the `nn.CrossEntropyLoss` class. Furthermore, the documentation also uses the following line of code

```
running_loss += loss.item()
```

Where does this `item()` method come from? I can't find a source mentioning `item()` online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If criterion is an object, then how can it be used as a function?

The criterion object has a `forward` method that is called in that case. `criterion(input, target)` is shorthand for `criterion.forward(input, target)`

> Where does this item() method come from?

This method returns a one dimensional `Tensor`. The single value can be accessed as a number with `item()`.